# How to remove one of the protobuf compiler that is making conflict?

Tags: anaconda, protocol-buffers, ubuntu-16.04, conda

I have installed protobuf using this `conda install protobuf==2.6.1` in a conda environment. So once I want to install a software it showing the following error message:

```
 #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
 #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
  ^
.build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
 #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
  ^
.build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
 #error your headers.
  ^
In file included from .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc:5:0:
.build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h:23:35: fatal error: google/protobuf/arena.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:588: recipe for target '.build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.o' failed
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.o] Error 1
```

I tried to find out which versions of protobuf has been installed

```
$sudo find / -name protoc
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/protoc
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
/home/ubuntu/anaconda2/pkgs/libprotobuf-3.4.1-h5b8497f_0/bin/protoc
/home/ununtu/anaconda2/envs/testenv/bin/protoc
```

after uninstalling the protobuf by this command `conda uninstall protobuf`, even after removing the compiler:

```
sudo apt-get remove protobuf-compiler
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove protobuf-compiler
$ protoc --version   ===>>> libprotoc 3.4.0
```

How can I uninstall this libprotoc 3.4.0? Even after removing by this command `sudo apt-get autoremove  protobuf-compiler libprotobuf-dev` and removing successfully, it still shows protoc version as `libprotoc 3.4.0`. Could someone please help? I only need `protobuf==2.6.1`. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I could solve the issue inside the anaconda environment:

```
conda uninstall libprotobuf
```